# How to push all the zip files from my computer desktop to s3 bucket (Public Access)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I currently have problem pushing all my zip files using the aws command. my location of my files is on my computer folder. so my main goal here is all of my zip files on my specific folder will transfer to the s3 bucket when i run the bat files command that i created.

> Fatal error: an error occured  when calling the ListObjects v2 operations: The Aws Key Id you provided not exist in our records.

**Please see the error below:**

[image: Error]

**Command:**

```
aws s3 cp s3://s3_folder/07-08-2020/*.zip  C:\first_folder\my_folder\update --recursive
```

**S3 Bucket:**

[image: S3]

Comment: Can you double check your access key. Seems you are using incorrect one.

Comment: you access key not exist.

Comment: hi @Marcin  how can i find the access key.? where i can put it on my desktop?

Comment: how can i set the access key on my desktop.?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html see this

Comment: Check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html) for details of how to setup the AWS CLI.

Comment: hi marcin  i already configure my aws, how ever when i try to used the command of aws s3 ls it shows an error occured (RequestTimeTooSkewed) when calling the listbuckets operations:

Comment: @Marcin i already solved thanks for the help. by changing the current time and date.

Comment: @DevGe If you don't mind I can provide an answer for future reference.

Comment: yah sure.. but there is problem i can't push the zip files.

Comment: @DevGe Is is some permissions issue? Coud consider making new question with the new error messages, details of the any bucket policies or IAM policies used for the upload.

Comment: yah sure i will create new thread for this. i don't where is the problem came from. i don't know if my command script is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by two factors:

1. Missing AWS credentials for AWS CLI
2. Incorrectly set data and time on the host computer

Instruction to setup the credentials for AWS CLI are:

- [Configuration and credential file settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html).